# algorithmically align audio to target

Tags: algorithm, audio

I have lots of different audio snippets recorded by Android phones of an event and I also have a recording made with high-end microphones and Apple Logic of the same event.

I would like to make a recording that flips back and forth between the Apple Logic recording and the phone recordings.  I originally just lined the recordings up at their start point, but what I've noticed is that the Android phone recordings will randomly skip anywhere from 10 to 100 samples here and there for reasons I don't get (the I/O code seems correct and is producing equally-sized files on all devices so I'm guessing that AudioRecorder is dropping samples).

So my question is - is there a tool or an algorithm people know of that can help run a batch job to identify where the audio is delayed (over a certain threshold) and insert silence so that things line up?  I have implemented a crude RMS-analyzer that tries to find a best fit between amplitudes of the recordings but that doesn't always make the right prediction...

If anyone knows of algorithms that have been proposed to do this sort of measurement, please let me know!

Comment: is your goal to align all the various source audio clips in time alignment so you can pick and choose which becomes the current source in the output mix ?  if so do the recordings have a sync able clock time metadata tag start time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the Android audio snippets into small parts (smaller than the expected amount of time between two skips). Then use cross-correlation of the parts to the reference. If the cross-correlation is strong then the part most probably does not contain a skip (or contains it close to or at one of the ends. If the cross-correlation is not strong, then there must be a skip somewhere in the middle of the part. For these parts, split them in half and repeat the correlation process for each part.